# Nested For statement exit and continue

Tags: vba, excel

I am using 2 for statements, 1 nested within another. What I am having issues with is when I exit the second statement and return to the first one I am unable to have the second statement go to the next cell, instead it keeps repeating itself.

for example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r&, c&, cel As Range
Dim r3&, c3&, cel3 As Range
Dim ri As Range
Dim CurrentSheet As String
Dim CurrentCell As String

CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Address    
r = ActiveCell.Row

For c = 26 To 31
    Sheets(CurrentSheet).Select

    Set cel = Cells(r, c)
    cel.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Cells(Target.Row, "B").Select
    Set ri = ActiveCell
    Sheets("Checklist").Select

    'For c2 = 1 To 31            
        Sheets("Checklist").Cells.Find(What:=ri.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

        For c3 = 25 To 30
            Sheets("checklist").Select
            r3 = Selection.Row
            Set cel3 = Sheets("checklist").Cells(r3, c3)
            cel3.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets(CurrentSheet).Select
            'Range(CurrentCell).Select
            'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            'CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Address
            'Exit For
        Next                        
    'Next
Next

Range(CurrentCell).Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True   

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that is not my actual code but rather an example of how it is structured. Instead of looping through columns 5 - 9 it just keeps selecting column 5.

Essentially what I am trying to do with the code is when a cell is changed on Sheet1 I want it to loop through each cell in that row (predetermined number of columns) and copy the cell value to sheet2 (Checklist for purposes of the code) and paste in a corresponding cell. The code also looks up and an identifier on sheet1 to find the correct row in sheet2.

Here is a link to the example file [Checklist Example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0jgh8FwPVvkMzByM0w0UlNuSXc)

Comment: you have a **Typo** : `For c 5 to 9` ? should not even compile, should be `For c = 5 to 9`. Also, where do you define and set `c3` ? Maybe it's better you describe better what you are trying to achieve, so we can offer you the right solution for your needs (instead of correcting this code's errors)

Comment: @ShaiRado I updated the code to include my actual code. I know there were some typos in the original sample that I provided. Hopefully the actual code will help a little bit.

Comment: you hvae this code in one of your worksheets ? in your `Worksheet_Change` event ? what should the code do?

Comment: @ShaiRado I included a copy of my template above. Upon first running the edit in "Assignments" and when you check "checklist" youll see that no changes have been made. If you step through the code you'll see that it does in fact copy values over to the different cells but it just over writes them.

Comment: Which cell `ri.Value` are you trying to find in `Sheets("Checklist")` ?  is it the `Target` (`ActiveCell` which is pressed, or `Cells(Target.Row, "B")` , the cell in the same row at Column "B" ? Are you trying to find `Emp#` ? or `RI Name` ?

Comment: 'ri.value' is selected on Assignments but found on checklist. And there is no specific value I am looking for other than what is in the row that was edited on assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you're after this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim f As Range
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D3:I11")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if user changed any cell outside "assigments" ones

    With Worksheets("Checklist") '<--\ reference "Checklist" sheet
        Set f = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Find(What:=Cells(Target.Row, 2), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<--| try finding "Emp #" from Assignments sheet changed cell row column B in referenced sheet ("i.e. "Checklist") column "A" cells not blank cells
        If f Is Nothing Then '<--| if "Emp #" match not found
            MsgBox "I couldn't find " & Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value & " in worksheet 'Checklist'"
        Else ' <-- if "Emp #" match found
            .Range("AA:AF").Rows(f.Row).Value = Range("AA:AF").Rows(Target.Row).Value '<--| paste "Assigmnents" sheet changed cell row columns "AA:AF" content in corresponiding columns of referenced sheet ("i.e. "Checklist") row where "Emp #" match was found
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I made a few minor tweaks to properly function with my workbook but otherwise it works exactly as I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like the shorter code version below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Cel As Range
Dim ri As Range
Dim FndRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Cel = Range(Cells(Target.Row, 26), Cells(Target.Row, 31))

Set ri = Cells(Target.Row, "B")
Set FndRng = Sheets("Checklist").Cells.Find(What:=ri.value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then '<-- find was successful
    Cel.Copy
    FndRng.Offset(, 25 - FndRng.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else ' <-- if Find failed raise an error message box
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & ri.value & " in Sheet 'Checklist'"
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```